# how do i make image selectable in ASp.net mvc 3 using jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have to do a one to one mapping of an image with characters. When the user clicks on images theses are selected and there is a "Map" option. i.e When the user clicks in map the images with characters are displayed. I have tried a number of things, but was unsuccessful. Here is my latest attempt:

**Jquery:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');    
    });
});
```

**Table:**

```
<div class="selected"> 
    <table> 
        <tr> 
            <td> <img src="../../Images/wi0096-48.gif" alt="Image1" class="conversation_img"/> </td> 
            <td> <img src="../../Images/down.png" alt ="image1"/> </td> 
            <td> <img src="../../Images/wi0054-48.gif" alt="Image1" /> </td> 
            <td> <img src="../../Images/Photo-icon.png" /> </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td> <img src="../../Images/wi0062-48.gif" /> </td> 
            <td> <img src="../../Images/wi0064-48.gif" /> </td> 
            <td> <img src="../../Images/wi0126-48.gif" /> </td> 
            <td> </td>
```

Above is my table with images. When I click on an image that should be selected and matched to some characters a to z dynamically. How do that in the .NET framework?

Comment: Can you post some markups with image and options?

Comment: <div class="selected">
    <table>
<tr>
<td>
  <img src="../../Images/wi0096-48.gif"  alt="Image1" class="conversation_img"/>
</td>
<td>
    <img src="../../Images/down.png"  alt ="image1"/>
     
</td>
<td>
    <img src="../../Images/wi0054-48.gif" alt="Image1" />
</td>
<td>
    <img src="../../Images/Photo-icon.png" />
</td>


</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <img src="../../Images/wi0062-48.gif" />
</td>
<td>
    <img src="../../Images/wi0064-48.gif" />
</td>
   
<td>
    <img src="../../Images/wi0126-48.gif" />
    
</td>
<td>
</td>

Comment: @afzaluh above is my table with images.When i click on image that should be selected and  matched to some characters a to z dynamically .How do that in .net framework